# How to add value of selected option to parent element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have part of a form (copied below), which contains a select dropdown.

What I would like to accomplish is to add the value of the selected option (five, ten or none) to **EDIT: the class of** the parent `<li>`.

I don't know much about jQuery and I don't know the search terms what I need to look for to find an answer to this.

```
<ul>
    <li>Name</li>
    <li>Email</li>
    <li class="budget" id="field_6_3">
        <label for="input_6_3" class="gfield_label">What budget do you have available?</label>
        <div class="ginput_container">
            <select tabindex="7" class="medium gfield_select" id="input_6_3" name="input_3">
                <option class="gf_placeholder" selected="selected" value="">please select...</option>
                <option value="five">5000</option>
                <option value="ten">10000</option>
                <option value="none">I haven't thought about this</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have tried a few things to add classes, but most add a class to all options, something like:

```
$('li.budget select').each(function(){           
    $(this).find('option').addClass( "newClass" );
});
```

I found how to get the value of the selected option `$( "#input_6_3" ).val();`, but I have no idea how to add that to the parent li.

Any tutorials or links there to are welcome.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Code snippets to update your class name of that parent `li`.

```js
$('li.budget select').change(function() {
  $(this).parent().parent("li").removeClass().addClass("budget " + $("#input_6_3").val());
});
```

```css
.budget.five {
  color: green;
}
.budget.ten {
  color: blue;
}
.budget.none {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Name</li>
  <li>Email</li>
  <li class="budget" id="field_6_3">
    <label for="input_6_3" class="gfield_label">What budget do you have available?</label>
    <div class="ginput_container">
      <select tabindex="7" class="medium gfield_select" id="input_6_3" name="input_3">
        <option class="gf_placeholder" selected="selected" value="">please select...</option>
        <option value="five">5000</option>
        <option value="ten">10000</option>
        <option value="none">I haven't thought about this</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You are welcome. I have updated styles for those classes also.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it :

HTML (added a span in your label to display the selected choice) :

```
<ul>
    <li>Name</li>
    <li>Email</li>
    <li class="budget" id="field_6_3">
        <label for="input_6_3" class="gfield_label">What budget do you have available? <span id="budget"></span></label>
        <div class="ginput_container">
            <select tabindex="7" class="medium gfield_select" id="input_6_3" name="input_3">
                <option class="gf_placeholder" selected="selected" value="">please select...</option>
                <option value="five">5000</option>
                <option value="ten">10000</option>
                <option value="none">I haven't thought about this</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JS :

```
//Each time something is selected (onchange)
$('li.budget select').change(function(){
    //sets the content of the #budget element by the selected option   
    $('#budget').text($(this).children('option:selected').text());
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/sozrdmmc/

Comment: Thanks, but please see my comment to @AhsN above

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
<ul>
    <li>Name</li>
    <li>Email</li>
    <li class="budget" id="field_6_3">
        <label for="input_6_3" class="gfield_label">What budget do you have available? </label><label class="choosen_option"></label>
        <div class="ginput_container">
            <select tabindex="7" class="medium gfield_select" id="input_6_3" name="input_3">
                <option class="gf_placeholder" selected="selected" value="">please select...</option>
                <option value="five">5000</option>
                <option value="ten">10000</option>
                <option value="none">I haven't thought about this</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>

$(".gfield_select").change(function(){
    $(".budget").removeClass("five ten none").addClass($(this).val());
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qyzjtzed/)

Comment: `.text()`  is more preferred ,since there is'nt any html

Comment: @dreamweiver alright :) Someone already posted an answer with `text()` though haha :)

Comment: @AhsN thanks for your answer. I realised I needed to ask my question a little bit better as I want to add the value to the **class** of the parent li, not replace it with. Sorry for that, I have edited my question to reflect this.
PS your snippet says #budget, but it should of course be .budget

Comment: @Piet I updated my code, and added CSS just for visually see the difference when the class is being changed :)

Answer (score 0):

Just try this!

```js
$(".gfield_select").change(function(){
    $(".choosen_option").text($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>Name</li>
    <li>Email</li>
    <li class="budget" id="field_6_3">
        <label for="input_6_3" class="gfield_label">What budget do you have available? </label><label class="choosen_option"></label>
        <div class="ginput_container">
            <select tabindex="7" class="medium gfield_select" id="input_6_3" name="input_3">
                <option class="gf_placeholder" selected="selected" value="">please select...</option>
                <option value="five">5000</option>
                <option value="ten">10000</option>
                <option value="none">I haven't thought about this</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I hope this will help you:)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specifically add it to the PARENT li, then you could use:

```
$('.gfield_select').on('change', function () {

    var value = $(this).val();

    $(this).parent('.ginput_container').parent('li').text(value);
});
```

Comment: I want to add the value as a class to the li. So it should become `<li class="budget five" id="field_6_3">` or `<li class="budget ten" id="field_6_3">` or `<li class="budget none" id="field_6_3">`